# Force at to email effective user instead of logged in user

Tags: rhel7, at, oel

The `at` scheduler is emailing an unexpected user consistently on both old RHEL6 boxen and new OEL7 boxen when the jobs produce output or when the `-m` flag is used.

If we log in to the box with our individual user accounts, then use `sudo su -` to switch to a different account and schedule jobs as that different account, `at` sends email to the user that logged in to the system initially rather than the (effective) user executing `at`.

Is there a way to change the environment such that `at` instead emails the effective user?

Of note from the `man` page:

`If at is executed from a su(1) shell, the owner of the login shell will receive the mail.`

Comment: Fyi, "sudo su -" expands to something like "sudo -u root su - root". If you check your processes, the root user is running "su", not you. I'm sorry that's not much help. What if you run "sudo at" directly?